# Calling connect() multiple times on UDP socket to send to different target address - valid?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, network-programming, udp

I'm working on a UDP communication protocol implementation.

I've got a question in regards to connect() call for UDP.

I want to use connect() and send() rather than sendto(). Usually the receiver end does not change. However, under certain circumstances, it might. 
Is it valid to call connect() on a UDP socket that already is connected to set a different target without closing and re-opening the socket (and by that loosing buffered received datagrams)?

I didn't find any documentation whether that is valid or not (so, testing might only tell me if it happens to work, which might not be portable). I am currently working with winsock2 on Windows 7, but want to be portable to other (newer) Windows versions and to linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for Linux, the manpage (man 2 connect) says OK:
' Generally,  connection-based protocol sockets may successfully connect() only once; connectionless protocol sockets may use connect() multiple times to change their association.  Connectionless sockets may dissolve the asso‐
       ciation by connecting to an address with the sa_family member of sockaddr set to AF_UNSPEC (supported on Linux since kernel 2.2).
'

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to know info about Windows :-) Or just try if it works and hope the behaviour doesn't change.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer for Windows, although it sounds like it's implemented similar to closing/reopening the socket : 'For a connectionless socket (for example, type SOCK_DGRAM), [...]. The default destination can be changed by simply calling connect again, even if the socket is already connected. Any datagrams queued for receipt are discarded if name is different from the previous connect.'